# boolean method issue in one sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, boolean

I have the following function in my model

```
after_save :update_status

def update_status
  if quantity_received >= quantity
    self.received = true
  else
    self.received = false
  end
end
```

True works great but it doesn't update to false when set to true. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're defining a callback it is very important you do not inadvertently return `false`, which is a signal to halt the chain, and that's what you're doing here in one case.

A re-written version that avoids this problem is:

```
after_save :update_status

def update_status
  self.received = quantity_received >= quantity

  return
end
```

You can return anything but `false`, so the last line could be `nil` or `true` just the same.

Comment: In this case I might not need to store this in the Db. If I do `def status
  quantity_received >= quantity ? true : false
end` How to render image_tag if true in the view?

Comment: There's no reason to do `cond ? true : false` because that's  equivalent to `cond` if the condition is a boolean, or `!!cond` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to received "after" save. So this assignment doesnt get saved!

Try

```
before_save :update_received

def update_received
  self.received = quantity_received >= quantity
end
```

And by "saved" i assume you mean "saved" in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The 2 solutions combined just work fine